# Retrieving salt+hash from DB for validation

Tags: php, mysql, hash, salt

So I'm in the process of learning PHP and am working on a login page. I already figured out how to register a new user using a SHA256 to hash $salt+$password. I know there are slower encryption methods like bcrypt but for learning purposes I'm just using SHA256. My question is, after using this to encrypt:

```
function HashPassword($password) {
  $salt = bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)); 
  $hash = hash("sha256", $salt . $password); column
  $final = $salt . $hash;
  return $final;
}
```

using prepared statements, what is the best way to retrieve the hash password from the database so I can validate it using a function like this?

```
function ValidatePassword($password, $hash_pass) {

  $salt = substr($hash_pass, 0, 64); 
  $trueHash = substr($hash_pass, 64, 64); 
  $reHash = hash("sha256" , $salt . $password); 

  return $reHash == $trueHash;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically save the password hashed with a salt to make it not recognizable.

In case your database gets hacked at some point, the hacker can't read the password directly. Instead he will have to recreate the hashed value.

If you don't use a different (random) salt for each user, the hacker will only have to create one table with all possible hash values and compare that to your saved hashed passwords.

If each password, however, has a different salt added to the password, before hashing, the hacker has to create a new table for each single password, thus increasing the effort needed to get the real passwords a lot. One hopes that this will make in inefficient or too costly for the hacker.

For you as a coder that wants to validate login credentials you have to follow the following pattern:

1. Get the salt saved in the database.
2. Compute the has value of the concatenated `hash = salt + password`
3. Compare the computed has with the saved one `hash === savedHash`
4. If they are the same, it was the valid password. If not, it was a wrong password.

Comment: Yes, I understand the concept and thank you for the additional clarification. What's tripping me up is how do I access the concatenated hash that is in my DB. select from users password where username='$username'?

Comment: @Jukodan you can do a single query to retrieve both salt and hashed password: `SELECT hashedPW, salt FROM users WHERE username='$username'`. The comparison is then done in PHP. The important point is to have different salts for every user and not a global one (The comment on the other answer sounds like you just have one "salt" for all users).

Comment: Ah! I was over thinking it, mainly because when I queried the database and echoed the result I received "resourced ID #2" instead of the expected hashed password. Currently I am using:

$salt = bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));

to generate a random salt for each user, then storing the hash = salt+password in one column.

Comment: So I took a break from it and am back at this. However, I'm still having trouble retrieving the value from the database. It simply returns a boolean value of true instead of a string, so my function can't do the comparison. Here is what I am using:

      `$row_result= $db_con->stmt_init();
       $sql_query = 'select password from users where username=?';
       $row_result->prepare($sql_query);
       $row_result->bind_param('s',$username);
       $row_result->execute();
       $hash_pass=$row_result->store_result();`

Comment: I then follow up with:

       `if(ValidatePassword($password, $hash_pass)){ 
         session_register("username"); //creates a session
 header("location:index.php");}`

Comment: @Jukodan Two things to note - `store_result()` doesn't parse the result object, but only saves it for later use. See `fetch_array()`, e.g., for parsing. Second you could retrieve the salt in the same query as the hashes password to save resources.

Comment: Thank you so much. I actually ended up using `bind_result($hash_pass)` followed by `fetch` as `fetch_array()` didn't work for me. You pointed me in the right direction though and I can continue learning. THANKS!!!

Answer (score 5):

The principle is that you *cant* retrieve the password; instead, you use the same `HashPassword` function to calculate a hash of the password attempt and then query the database for matching records.

---

**EDIT**

Looking again at your `HashPassword` function, I realise that you don't want to generate the random salt therein, but rather take `$salt` as an argument; you will either pass in the value from your existing database record, or pass in a randomly generated one, as appropriate.

Comment: What about the salt though? I know people are able to validate logins that were hashed using the salt. In this case, since it is randomly generated how exactly can I validate...I'm a little lost.

Comment: @Jukodan: Your salt should be stored together with your record.

Comment: I keep my salt as a global class variable (private) on the include scripts in which I need the hash + salt.  Just take their entered password, add your salt to it, store it in a variable, retrieve their already hashed password from the db and compare the two.  If they match, then you're golden, if not, then they entered the wrong password